# Yii2 - behaviour of a controller

Tags: yii2

Learning about behaviour of a controller.

In this controller, I got a lot of action that should be access after login.
How can I make one special action in this controller without login ?

I just try it, not succces. This is my code.

```
class RequestController extends Controller {
public function behaviors() {
 return [
  'verbs' => [
      'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
      'actions' => [
      'delete' => ['post'],
      'bulk-delete' => ['post'],
    ],
  ],

  'access' => [
      'class' => AccessControl::className(),
      'only' => ['approve'], /*Special action*/
      'rules' => [
          [
              'actions' => ['approve'],
              'allow' => false,
              'roles' => ['?'],
          ],
      ],
  ],
];
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You need use in rules 
`'allow' => true`, this is described here:
[Yii2 authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should assign

```
'access' => [
  'class' => AccessControl::className(),
  'only' => ['approve'], /*Special action*/
  'rules' => [
      [
          'actions' => ['approve'],
          'allow' => true,
          'roles' => ['?'],
      ],
  ],
],
```